# Laptop randomly hangs, cannot open any programs

Tags: laptop, freeze, windows-10

After being powered on for some time, my HP laptop running Windows 10 will lapse into an unusual half-frozen state. It does not seem to slow down, but I cannot open any programs or perform various other actions.

These are some of the things I CANNOT do:

- Open any programs from the taskbar or desktop icons. This includes Task Manager.
- Open the Start menu.
- Use Ctrl-Alt-Del or Ctrl-Shift-Esc. Nothing happens when I press them.

However, these are some of the things that I still CAN do:

- Use any programs that were already open when the computer froze.
- Close any open programs. They are then unable to be reopened.
- Use Windows-R to get the Run dialog and open CMD from it. Trying to shut down the computer from the prompt just hangs and never completes.

The only way that I can get the computer working again so far is to shut it down by holding the power button, then turn it back on. The computer will work normally for some time after the restart, but it will eventually freeze again.

**Update:** This HP laptop came with hardware diagnostic tools that can be started from the BIOS. I ran the full hardware test, and the laptop shut off during the memory test. I also ran Windows Memory Diagnostic from the Control Panel, and the laptop shut off during it as well.

Comment: "the laptop shut off during the memory test" so you have some bad ram ...

Comment: Did you figure the cause? I have this same issue on my Acer V15 Nitro gaming laptop with the exception that I can reboot my computer. Rebooting always fixes it. It's happens 100% of the time within 3 days after turning on my computer. I think the memory issue you're seeing is a red herring. Bad memory would cause random errors in various places. It wouldn't cause the same problem every time. I ran Memtest86+ didn't find any errors on my computer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I never figured out the cause; one day it just stopped happening. I originally assumed that system files were corrupted, but SFC didn't find any errors either.